# Windows Phone 10 SMS save - not avaiable to install apps

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-930

I can not install apps (error message: 0x800B0101) to my Nokia Lumia 930, but I have a lot of SMS what I would like to keep for the future. How can I save this SMS without installing apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was the common problem which have an issue with the Back up

please try the following steps.

1) restart the Phone cheek the date and time.

2) Deactivate the back up restart once more

3) volume down and power button until device restarts.

4) Verify that the date and time is correct.

5) Activate the back up and have a look if the same happens.

6) Try over WiFi and over data connection.

I hope it'll help you